# isMemberOfClass problem

Tags: objective-c, class, member

I'm trying to log if an object in my mutable array is a member of the class `NSString`. Here is my code:

```
 id obj = [mutArr objectAtIndex:1];
 BOOL classMem = [obj isMemberOfClass:[NSString class]];
 NSLog(@"%@", classMem);
```

Instead of printing `YES` or `NO`, I get the output `(null)`. Can you please tell me why this is the case?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOL` is not an object, so shouldn't be logged with `%@`. Log it with the format string `%d` instead. Or, if you want more legible output, you can use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", classMem ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: And when you've fixed that, you'll find that almost none of the strings in the array answers yes.  NSString is a class cluster and almost all strings are actually instances of subclasses of NSString.  You should be using `-isKindOfClass:` not `-isMemberOfClass:`